# In Neo4j how to exclude results of one query from another

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have two queries

`MATCH (a:User)-[:Likes]->(b:Object)
    WHERE <condition on b>
RETURN a`

`MATCH (a:User)-[:HasVisited]->(c:Location)
    WHERE <condition on c>
RETURN a`

I want to combine the two. Such that I have results from query2 that donot fit query1

So far I have tried the following

`MATCH (a:User)-[:Likes]->(b:Object)
 MATCH (a:User)-[:HasVisited]->(c:Location)
 WHERE 
    <condition on c>
    AND NOT <condition on b>
 RETURN a`

but this approach does not exclude all results that i wanted excluded.

`MATCH (a:User)-[:Likes]->(b:Object)
    WHERE <condition on b>
WITH collect(DISTINCT a) as exc
MATCH (a:User)-[:HasVisited]->(c:Location)
    WHERE <condition on c>
    AND NOT a IN exc
RETURN a`

This gives the right results but gets inefficient once query1 and query2 start becoming more complicated

I have also tried

`MATCH (a:User)-[:Likes]->(b:Object)
    WHERE <condition on b>
WITH collect(DISTINCT a) as exc
MATCH (a:User)
    WHERE NOT a IN exc
    WITH a
MATCH MATCH (a:User)-[:HasVisited]->(c:Location)
    WHERE <condition on c>
RETURN a`

I had hoped reducing the number of nodes that a can match against upfront would improve performance but this approach doesnt seem to work any better.

Is there a standard/better way to exclude results matching one query from another?

Comment: I am not aware of a better way as there is no `MINUS` operator in Cypher. Using `collect` and `IN` seems to be the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first example is that it could still match some relation for `(a:User)-[:Likes]->(b:Object)` where 'b' does not meet the condition, while you want to completely exclude 'a' from the results when it is related to the selected 'b'.

To achieve this you could use an [OPTIONAL MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/optional-match/) clause:

```
MATCH (a:User)-[:HasVisited]->(c:Location)
WHERE <condition on c>
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:Likes]->(b:Object)
WHERE <condition on b>
WITH a, b, c
WHERE b IS NULL
RETURN a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some like this:

```
MATCH (U1:User)-[:HasVisited]->(L:Location) 
    WHERE <condition on c>
WITH distinct U1
OPTIONAL MATCH (U2:User)-[:Likes]->(O:Object) 
    WHERE U2 = U1 AND 
          <condition on b>
WITH U1, 
     count(U2) as excl 
    WHERE excl = 0
RETURN U1
```